# How to create concentric ellipses in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I can draw **parallel** **concentric ellipses (oval shape lines)** just **like the grey, oval dashed lines in the picture below in my R plot?**

**Here is my small R code:**

```
plot(1, ty='n', ann = F, bty = "l", tcl = F )
text(1, 1, "?", cex = 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the draw.ellipse() from the plotrix package like this (you will need to adjust some values to get exactly what you want):

```
# your code
plot(1, ty='n', ann = F, bty = "l", tcl = F )
text(1, 1, "?", cex = 5)

# code to create concentric ovals
library(plotrix)
draw.ellipse(x= rep(1,9), y= rep(1,9), a= seq(.1, .9, by = .1), b= seq(.05, .45, by = .05), lty = 2)
```

- x and y are the coordinates of the center.
- a and b give the radii of the ovals
- lty defines the line type